# How can I reuse one Bootstrap modal div?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'd like to be able to have a number of different links on a page reuse one modal div via Bootstrap's modal plugin:

```
<h3>This button shows a modal (<code>#utility</code>) with text "Phasellus <em>tincidunt gravida</em>..."</h3>
<br />
<a id="file_attach" data-toggle="modal" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/jhfrench/6K8rD/show/" data-target="#utility" class="btn">Modal 1</a><br />
<h3>This button should invoke the same modal (<code>#utility</code>), but fill it with text "Phasellus <em>egestas est eu</em>..."</h3>
<br />
<a id="file_attach" data-toggle="modal" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/jhfrench/AWSnt/show/" data-target="#utility" class="btn">Modal 2</a><br />

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="utility" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Click outside modal to close it</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…this is getting replaced with content that comes from passed-in href</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd expect that clicking on either link (which are styled as buttons) would invoke the modal and load the modal with the page (value of `href`) corresponding to the clicked button. Instead, the modal always loads with the content of the link you click first; the modal does not "refresh" with content that should be dictated by `href` of the "other" link.

I think this is a Bootstrap bug, but I'm asking the question here in case I'm using it incorrectly.

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/qv5u5/ for a demonstration.

Comment: have you tried to call the removeData function? Something like: $('body').on('hidden', '.modal', function () {
  $(this).removeData('modal');
});

Comment: @Scott: tried it (see fiddle), but no joy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After further research, I found a few Bootstrap issues mentioning this behaviour [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/5514) and [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5161#issuecomment-9840901). I've asked for [issue 5514](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/5514) to be reopened.

Meanwhile, this jQuery will patch up the problem*:

```
$('a[data-toggle="modal"]').on('click', function(){
    // update modal header with contents of button that invoked the modal
    $('#myModalLabel').html( $(this).html() );
    //fixes a bootstrap bug that prevents a modal from being reused
    $('#utility_body').load(
        $(this).attr('href'),
        function(response, status, xhr) {
            if (status === 'error') {
                //console.log('got here');
                $('#utility_body').html('<h2>Oh boy</h2><p>Sorry, but there was an error:' + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText+ '</p>');
            }
            return this;
        }
    );
});​
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/qv5u5/51/ for a working example.*

*-For some reason, sometimes when you click the button in the fiddle the modal will show blank. This is not a problem in the application I'm working with, so I suspect it's a problem unrelated to this question/answer.

Comment: This answer works on all browsers and allows me to customize the label a bit more per link using jQuery selectors. Thanks!

Comment: This worked great!  Hopefully this will get patched to the main Bootstrap branch.

Comment: @Jeromy: even though the OP said the approach `$(this).removeData('modal');` does not work, I got it working just fine on the same fiddle. Could you explain how your patch works better than the `removeData` ?

Comment: Just a heads up to anyone wanting to reuse certain modal(s), but still want to be able to either load two modals at once or not over-write previous data in a given modal (for whatever reason, i.e. prevent additional ajax requests for data that is already loaded). If this is you, place this line: **var target_modal_id_str = $(this).data("target");** as the first line within the on click binding function, and then use **$(target_modal_id_str)** as the scoped modal container. Just ran into this issue myself so I thought I'd share the solution.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of having to write html markups of modal and manipulate it via javascript, I would use Bootstrap-Dialog to ease everything:

```
$('.modal-btn').click(function(event){
    var $link = $(this);
    new BootstrapDialog({
        title   :   'Load content of : ' + $link.attr('href'),
        content :   $('<div>Loading...</div>').load($link.attr('href')),
        buttons :   [{
            label   :   'Close',
            onclick :   function(dialog){
                dialog.close();
            }
        }, {
            label   :   'Save changes',
            cssClass:   'btn-primary',
            onclick :   function(dialog){
                alert('The content of the dialog is: ' + dialog.getBody().html());
                dialog.close();
            }
        }]
    }).open();

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

See here for a live demo, it loads the two urls you provided in your example:
http://jsfiddle.net/txrM8/

See more about Bootstrap-Dialog:
http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap-dialog/